# Приставки на -з и -с

Tags: орфография

Недавно в сборнике Е.С. Симаковой "Новый справочник для подготовки к ОГЭ" обнаружила информацию о том, что слово *безвкусный* является исключением к правилу о приставках на *-з, -с*. Объясните, кому не трудно, почему это слово исключение?      Больше нигде подобной информации не нашла.

Answer (score 4):

> Недавно в сборнике Е.С. Симаковой "Новый справочник для подготовки к
>   ОГЭ" обнаружила информацию о том, что слово Безвкусный является
>   исключением к правилу о приставках на -з, -с. Объясните, кому не
>   трудно, почему это слово исключение? Больше нигде подобной информации
>   не нашла.

К сожалению, Вы не привели **правило**, которое использует Симакова. **А ведь формулировки этого правила у разных лингвистов разные.**

Формулировка в [Правилах-56](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/128-sogl-19-14) (*"в приставках без-, воз-, вз-, из-, низ-, раз-, роз-, чрез- (через-) перед глухими к, п, с, т, ф, х, ц, ч, ш, щ пишется с вместо з"*) мало чем отличается от формулировок в разных справочниках Розенталя. Однако формулировка эта может допускать **двоякую трактовку**: могут иметься в виду **звуки**, а могут -- и **буквы**.

В.Н. Светлышева вводит уточнение, указывающее на **звуки**:  *«в соответствии с произношением перед гласными и звонкими согласными пишется **з**, перед глухими – **с**»* [Н.С. Валгина, В.Н. Светлышева. "Русский язык. Орфография и пунктуация."  М., 2002].

Т.М. Григорьева прямо говорит о **звуках**: *«Приставки на з- <...> меняют согласную в зависимости от последующего звонкого / глухого **звука**»* [Т.М. Григорьева. "Русский язык: Орфоэпия. Графика. Орфография." М., 2004].

В [ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=44#pp44) правило формулируется иначе: *«§ 82… перед буквами, передающими глухие согласные, пишется буква **с**, а в остальных случаях – буква **з**».*

И исключений из этого правила для слова *"безвкусный"* авторы ПАС не предусматривали, считая, что написание его полностью укладывается в формулировку правила.

Но всё же и эта формулировка может трактоваться двояко.

В вышедшей несколько лет назад книге *"Русское письмо в правилах с комментариями" (М., 2011)* Е.В. Бешенкова и О.Е. Иванова (**один из авторов ПАС**) предложили более точную, по их мнению, формулировку:

*«Приставки на **з/с** пишутся с буквой **з** перед гласными, буквой **в** и перед буквами, **основными значениями которых является передача звонкого согласного**».* При такой формулировке обеспечивалось бы не только написание слов ***безвкусный, безвкусица, бессбросовый*** (РОС), но и потенциальных слов типа *черезвторниковый, бессбруйный, бессбойный* (т. е. никаких исключений из правила не было бы).

Но это было предложением на будущее.

В вышедшем в этом году *"Объяснительном русском орфографическом словаре-справочнике"* Е.В. Бешенкова, О.Е. Иванова и Л.К. Чельцова  сформулировали правило, уже опираясь на **звуки**:

> ***Правило.*** В конце слова или в конце первой части слова перед дефисом и внутри слова перед согласным (не сонорным или **в**) пишется
>   та же согласная, которая выступает в той же значимой части слова, но
>   перед гласным или сонорным и **в**, напр.: ро**з** -- так как
>   ро**з**а…
>
> ***Исключения***... (ряд исключений).
>
> ***Исключение-подправило.*** Приставки на **з/с** пишутся с буквой **з** перед гласными, сонорными и звонкими согласными, а перед глухими согласными пишутся с буквой **с**…
>
> ***Исключения:*** слово **безвкусный** -- **з** перед глухим звуком **[ф]**...

и далее ряд других исключений.

Comment: А Грамота.ру. сформулировало это правило более лаконично, правда, об исключении ничего не говорится.

Comment: В приставках, оканчивающихся на З и С, написание конечной согласной зависит от произношения: перед глухими согласными произносят [с] и пишут «с», а перед звонкими согласными и гласными произносят [з] и пишут «з».

Comment: _...а перед звонкими согласными и гласными произносят [з] и пишут «з»_  === Не всегда. См.  _БЕССБРОСОВЫЙ_. В этом слове пишется "бес", а произносится "без".

Comment: Поэтому я написал: ''...Об исключении ничего не говорится''.

Comment: _Серж: А Грамота.ру. сформулировало это правило более лаконично..._ === Серж, Вы что-то путаете. По-моему, Грамота.ру **никаких правил** на этот счёт не формулировала. А то, что формулировалось в Правилах-56 (скорее всего, что именно их Вы имеете в виду), разными авторами трактовалось по-разному (см. выше). Потому у некоторых авторов "безвкусный" и попало в исключения.

Answer (score 3):

Звук С перед звонким В   не озвончается, у пары З/С перед В **сильная фонетическая позиция**, поэтому мы различаем: зверь - сверь.

В слове "безвкусный" мы пишем З, а произносим С, то есть пишем **не по слуху**, а в соответствии с фонематическим принципом русского письма (фонетическое чередование не отражается на письме, морфемный состав приставки один и тот же), в то время как все остальные приставки пишутся **по слуху**, то есть для них используется фонетический принцип письма (фонетическое чередование отражается на письме).

Проверить звуковой состав приставки можно **по сильной позиции перед гласными и сонорными:** безосновательный, безрадостный. Перед другими согласными происходит **фонетическое чередование**, которое в виде исключения отражается на письме: бесконечный.

Comment: Вера, о каком исключении идет речь? Сможете объяснить? В слове ''безвкусный'' буква з пишется по правилу. Если, конечно, имелось виду это исключение. И о каком чередовании Вы говорите?  Я, честно говоря, не понял. И при чем тут буква с перед з? Здесь перед в стоит з, а не с.

Comment: В приставках на З/С используется фонетический принцип письма: как слышится, так и пишется.  Но в слове "безвкусный" слышится С, а пишется З, это и есть исключение (запись не по слуху).

Comment: Да, но это связано с тем, что буква В находится перед глухим согласным.

Comment: А есть ли другие такие примеры? Не знаете?

Comment: Я думаю, что это слова такой структуры: без+ в + глухой согласный, именно он последовательно оглушает В и З.

Comment: Да, полностью согласен. Но можно ли в этом случае говорить об исключении?

Comment: Но других исключений нет, хотя этот вопрос больше подходит для олимпиад, а не для экзамена.

Comment: _Серж: А есть ли другие такие примеры? Не знаете?_  === _БЕССБРОСОВЫЙ_ (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%91%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%91%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%AB%D0%99&all=x ). В этом слове  приставка пишется не так, как слышится.

Comment: Да, получается уже ряд исключений.

Comment: _Vera: В слове "безвкусный" мы пишем З… **по общему правилу** для приставок на З/С._ === А речь-то в вопросе шла о том, почему это слово является в учебнике Симаковой исключением именно **из правил**.

Comment: Смотря о каком правиле идет речь. Есть такое правило: Выбор З/С в приставках делается по слуху: как пишется, так и слышится. Исключение: в слове безвкусный слышится С, а пишется З.

Comment: _Vera: **Есть такое правило**: Выбор З/С в приставках делается по слуху: как пишется, так и слышится._ ===  Гм... Это откуда? В Правилах-56 такого нет, у Розенталя нет, в ПАС нет... А где есть?

Comment: А про фонетический принцип орфографии что-нибудь слышали?

Comment: _Vera : А про фонетический принцип орфографии что-нибудь слышали?_ === Немножко слышал... Но речь-то не о нём, а о ПРАВИЛАХ. Почему ни Правила-56, ни Розенталь, ни ПАС не включали слово "безвкусный" в исключения из ПРАВИЛ написания приставок на З/С, а Симакова -- включила?  А не включали Розенталь и др. это слово в исключения только потому, что ориентировались в трактовке правила на написание БУКВ в слове, а НЕ НА ЗВУКИ. Идёт после приставки БУКВА "В"  -- значит перед ней должно писаться "З". Вот и всё.  Симакова же, видимо, использовала  правила от Светлышевой, Бешенковой, Ивановой...

Comment: Всё замечательно: люди занимаются научной деятельностью, придумывают правила на пустом месте, называют их своими именами и т.д.   А ситуация абсолютно элементарная: просто надо понимать, что все приставки пишутся в соответствии с фонематическим принципом, а приставки на З/С - в соответствии с фонетическим принципом, то есть в основном по слуху:  З  перед гласными и звонкими согласными, С - перед глухими согласными. И вдруг находится слово, где С пишется перед В, потому что после В следует  глухой согласный, и всё сочетание ЗВК  оглушается.

Comment: И конечно, это великое открытие, о котором все должны знать и говорить. А вообще-то  в этой теме есть только один ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО ИНТЕРЕСНЫЙ ВОПРОС: почему приставки  на З/С не пишутся так, как все? В 1918 году могли бы перейти к их всеобщему фонематическому письму, а перешли, напротив, к фонетическому, есть ли у наших лингвистов хоть какая-нибудь версия? Вот что надо изучать, а не впутывать школьников в свою псевдонауку.

Answer (score 3):

Юлия, насколько понимаю, тут совместными усилиями уже нашли ответ.

Я позволю себе только сформулировать его предельно кратко, чтобы отсечь все комментарии не по сути. И дать прямой ответ именно **на поставленный вопрос**.

*Упоминание "исключения" здесь есть не более чем следствие принятой в пособии формулировки правила. В той формулировке принято, что выбор С/З в приставках определяется не написанием начала корня, а произношением. При таком подходе "безвкусный" и некоторые другие становятся исключениями*.

Подробнее - у slava1947 и Vera.
(А вообще - в топку такие пособия, тень на плетень наводящие. Зачем усложнять-то то, что всем всегда вполне понятно было и логично при традиционном подходе?)